# join table referencing non unique foreign key

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, schema

I have the following tables in a database. `phrases` allows duplicate phrases to be stored.

```
CREATE TABLE phrases (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    phrase VARCHAR(1000),
    creation_date TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE intents (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(10) UNIQUE
);
```

I would like to create a join table between phrases and intents. I want to enforce that:

- each phrase exists in the phrases table
- each phrase only appears once

The following fails because the foreign key in `phrases` is not unique.

```
CREATE TABLE phrases_intents (
    phrase VARCHAR(1000) REFERENCES phrases (phrase),
    intent VARCHAR(10) REFERENCES intents (name),
    PRIMARY KEY (phrase),
);
```

What is best practice to allow this functionality?

Comment: Why do you allow duplicates in the `phrases` table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the phrases table to have a unique key for foreign key relationships.  Perhaps:

```
CREATE TABLE phrases (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    phrase VARCHAR(1000),
    creation_date TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
    unique (phrase, id)
);
```

Then use this key in `phrase_intents`:

```
CREATE TABLE phrase_intents (
    phrase_intents_id serial primary key,
    phrase varchar(1000) not null,
    phrase_id int not null, 
    intent_id int references intents (id),
    foreign key (phrase, phrase_id) references phrases(phrase, id),
    unique (phrase)
);
```

Your conditions are satisfied:

1. Each `phrase` is in the `phrases` table because of `not null` and the foreign key reference.
2. Each distinct phrase appears in this table at most once.  This is because of the unique constraint on `phrase`.

For each phrase to appear *exactly* once requires populating the table.  You will then need triggers on your table to be sure that when a new phrase is created, then a row is inserted.